# How do I use valueComponent prop to render the selected Item if I am using optionsRenderer in react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

Say I have my react-select component with the following props. I am using pug syntax.

What works

My dropdown displays every option correctly with all options custom rendered using the `optionsRenderer` prop...

[image: react select options custom rendered]

#### What I get(as expected)

However the results I get are that the input value is just a text I have referenced in my `option.label` field. In the first option, `Custom` is my label key.

[image: value of input is the label key in the options]

#### What I want to achieve

use the `valueComponent` to display exactly what the same HTML that options renderer is displaying inside the options dropdown.

Like this, styling can be improved of course :)

[image: custom value rendered using valueComponent]

...

```
  Select(
    options=this.getOptions()
    optionRenderer=customOption
    valueComponent=customOption // this doesn't work
    valueKey="id"
  )
```

The function below is expected by the `optionRenderer` props and iterates on the options supplied.

```
const customOption = (option) => pug`
  div
    strong #{option.label}
    p #{option.renderMethod}

  div
   strong $#{option.otherHTMLData}
`
```

But `valueComponent` only expects 1 static component. Therefore any function like `() => <span>Will show this</span>`

How do I get the option that is selected to be used as the input value using `valueComponent`?

Answer (score 0):

The label displayed by the `ValueContainer` depends on `isMutli`. If `isMulti` is false, you control this display by overriding the `SingleValue` component. If `isMulti` is true, you control this display by overriding the `MultiValue` component (more specifically, it's `MultiValueLabel` component).

See the [Components documentation](https://react-select.com/components#replaceable-components) for some simple examples.